# Two column three image combination layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm just trying to make fluid responsive layout through `<img src="" alt="" />` tags but I made it through background image.

Is there any way to make this layout with `img` tag ?

XD Example[image]

Front End Code

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cmd-three-img-container {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
}

.cmd-main-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.cmd-img-stacked {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cmd-img-overlay {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.cmd-img-overlay h4 {
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.cmd-top-img,
.cmd-bottom-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(50% - 2.5px);
}

.cmd-top-img {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}

.cmd-bottom-img {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/hxiPgcK.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.cmd-top-img {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="cmd-three-img-container">
        <!-- top level image container START-->

        <div class="cmd-img-stacked">
          <!--stacked img container -->
          <div class="cmd-top-img">
          </div>
          <div class="cmd-bottom-img">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cmd-main-img">
          <!--Main image -->
          <div class="cmd-img-overlay">
            <!--overlay div -->
            <h4>Office</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="cmd-three-img-container">
        <!-- top level image container START-->

        <div class="cmd-img-stacked">
          <!--stacked img container -->
          <div class="cmd-top-img">
          </div>
          <div class="cmd-bottom-img">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cmd-main-img">
          <!--Main image -->
          <div class="cmd-img-overlay">
            <!--overlay div -->
            <h4>Office</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="cmd-three-img-container">
        <!-- top level image container START-->

        <div class="cmd-img-stacked">
          <!--stacked img container -->
          <div class="cmd-top-img">
          </div>
          <div class="cmd-bottom-img">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cmd-main-img">
          <!--Main image -->
          <div class="cmd-img-overlay">
            <!--overlay div -->
            <h4>Office</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="cmd-three-img-container">
        <!-- top level image container START-->

        <div class="cmd-img-stacked">
          <!--stacked img container -->
          <div class="cmd-top-img">
          </div>
          <div class="cmd-bottom-img">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cmd-main-img">
          <!--Main image -->
          <div class="cmd-img-overlay">
            <!--overlay div -->
            <h4>Office</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="cmd-three-img-container">
        <!-- top level image container START-->

        <div class="cmd-img-stacked">
          <!--stacked img container -->
          <div class="cmd-top-img">
          </div>
          <div class="cmd-bottom-img">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cmd-main-img">
          <!--Main image -->
          <div class="cmd-img-overlay">
            <!--overlay div -->
            <h4>Office</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="cmd-three-img-container">
        <!-- top level image container START-->

        <div class="cmd-img-stacked">
          <!--stacked img container -->
          <div class="cmd-top-img">
          </div>
          <div class="cmd-bottom-img">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cmd-main-img">
          <!--Main image -->
          <div class="cmd-img-overlay">
            <!--overlay div -->
            <h4>Office</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="cmd-three-img-container">
        <!-- top level image container START-->

        <div class="cmd-img-stacked">
          <!--stacked img container -->
          <div class="cmd-top-img">
          </div>
          <div class="cmd-bottom-img">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cmd-main-img">
          <!--Main image -->
          <div class="cmd-img-overlay">
            <!--overlay div -->
            <h4>Office</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="cmd-three-img-container">
        <!-- top level image container START-->

        <div class="cmd-img-stacked">
          <!--stacked img container -->
          <div class="cmd-top-img">
          </div>
          <div class="cmd-bottom-img">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cmd-main-img">
          <!--Main image -->
          <div class="cmd-img-overlay">
            <!--overlay div -->
            <h4>Office</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use img + javascript

Comment: Can you elaborate through code ?

Comment: $('.imagebox').each(function () {
     $(this).find('img').addClass('imgtag');
     var imgSrc = $(this).find('.imgtag').attr('src');
     imgSrc = "url(" + imgSrc + ")";
     $(this).css("background-image", imgSrc);
 });

Comment: I'd say give each `<img/>` element `display: block`. Then surround each block of 3 images with a `<div/>` container. Then start messing around with `float: left` on the images. That should a be point into the right direction. Obviously each `<div/>` container should also be in their own container to have them next to eachother. Or use bootstrap rows / columns for that.

Comment: Why not use object-fit instead? If you really do it with img tag

Comment: @Rafv I thought, but I'm confused about  `object-fit`

Comment: You could also do something like `<div class="row"><div class="col s3"><div class="row"><div class="col s6"><img id="1"><img id="2"></div><div class="col s6"><img id="3"></div></div><div class="col s3">...` etc. Basicly just making use of Bootstrap's rows and colums to position them

Comment: Sorry, used [Materialize CSS](https://materializecss.com/) styling there out of habit. Though if your project isn't too large yet, I'd recommend using Materialize instead of Bootstrap. It's easier and much more professional looking. Unlike Bootstrap, it doesn't mess around with your intended design and gives you real mobile menu's instead of weird dropdown menu's.

Comment: Just put your img tag inside your stacked img container, declare object-fit and youre done. But it's still need polyfill for IE, if your in mind. @Momin

Comment: But I used bootstrap for this project @icecub

Comment: Could you explain what is the problem with background image? Why you would like to use `<img />` instead?

Comment: @Momin My answer was not helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just split the child column within the parent column and add the bootstrap 4 default class `d-flex align-items-stretch h-100` stretch the image until column end. set `border-radis` for corners separately as per your requirement. I hope this example you will find the solution.

```css
.row.eqcol {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.row.eqcol div[class^="col-"] {
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.text-overlay h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
.text-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
.cmd-three-img-container {
    position: relative;
}
.cmd-three-img-container img {
    object-fit: cover;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container my-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="row eqcol">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="cmd-three-img-container left-col">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="cmd-three-img-container d-flex align-items-stretch h-100 right-col">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        <div class="text-overlay">
                            <h3>Office</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="row eqcol">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="cmd-three-img-container left-col">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="cmd-three-img-container d-flex align-items-stretch h-100 right-col">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        <div class="text-overlay">
                            <h3>Office</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="row eqcol">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="cmd-three-img-container left-col">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="cmd-three-img-container d-flex align-items-stretch h-100 right-col">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        <div class="text-overlay">
                            <h3>Office</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="row eqcol">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="cmd-three-img-container left-col">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="cmd-three-img-container d-flex align-items-stretch h-100 right-col">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9Q9pgmR.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        <div class="text-overlay">
                            <h3>Office</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```